# Reshape data to long format based on the first letter of the variable names

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

I am trying to reshape my data to long format based on the first letter of the variable names. I have data from mothers and fathers and they are indicated by the first letter of the variables, like in this dataset:

```
toydat <- data.frame(id=1:10,
           mincome=rep(sample(1:5), 2),
           medu=rep(sample(1:5), 2),
           methnicity=rep(sample(1:5), 2),
           fincome=rep(sample(1:5), 2),
           fedu=rep(sample(1:5), 2),
           fethnicity=rep(sample(1:5), 2)
)
```

Eventually the data should look like this

```
 gender income   edu ethnicity 
 mother      3     4         3
 mother      2     2         4
 mother      5     3         2
 mother      3     4         2
 mother      4     3         3
 mother      2     2         1
 mother      3     3         4
 mother      4     4         4
 mother      3     3         5
 mother      2     2         1
 father      5     5         2
 father      3     3         3
 father      4     2         2
 father      2     2         4
 father      3     1         5
 father      4     4         1
 father      4     5         2
 father      3     2         3
 father      3     3         2
 father      1     2         1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
Thanks to @akrun, and my original question was solved. I was wondering what if gender indicators `m` or `f` is at the end of the names. How to `names_sep` in a regex way?

By trying the following code, the variables are not split although the gender variable is created.

```
toydat %>% 
     select(-id) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
                  names_to = c(".value", "gender"), 
                  names_sep = "(<=[a-z])(?=[mf]$)") %>%
     mutate(gender = case_when(gender == 'm' ~ 'mother', TRUE ~ 'father'))
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   gender mincome  medu methnicity fincome  fedu fethnicity
   <chr>    <int> <int>      <int>   <int> <int>      <int>
 1 father       1     3          4       5     5          5
 2 father       5     4          3       3     1          4
 3 father       3     2          2       1     4          2
 4 father       2     1          1       4     2          1
 5 father       4     5          5       2     3          3
 6 father       1     3          4       5     5          5
 7 father       5     4          3       3     1          4
 8 father       3     2          2       1     4          2
 9 father       2     1          1       4     2          1
10 father       4     5          5       2     3          3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We remove the 'id' column, then pivot to long format with all the columns, specify the `names_se`p to split between the 'm' or 'f' at the start (`^`) of the string and the next letter in a regex lookaround and then recode the 'gender' column by changing the 'm' to 'mother' and 'f' to 'father' in `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
toydat %>% 
   select(-id) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
     names_to = c("gender", ".value"), 
        names_sep = "(?<=^[mf])(?=[a-z])") %>%
   mutate(gender = case_when(gender == 'm' ~ 'mother', TRUE ~ 'father'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#   gender income   edu ethnicity
#   <chr>   <int> <int>     <int>
# 1 mother      3     5         3
# 2 father      4     5         5
# 3 mother      4     3         5
# 4 father      3     1         1
# 5 mother      2     1         2
# 6 father      2     3         3
# 7 mother      1     2         1
# 8 father      5     2         4
# 9 mother      5     4         4
#10 father      1     4         2
#11 mother      3     5         3
#12 father      4     5         5
#13 mother      4     3         5
#14 father      3     1         1
#15 mother      2     1         2
#16 father      2     3         3
#17 mother      1     2         1
#18 father      5     2         4
#19 mother      5     4         4
#20 father      1     4         2
```

The output values differ from expected as the OP used `sample` without `set.seed` while constructing the input example

---

For the edited part, we switch the `names_to` and change the `names_sep` regex lookaround switched as well

```
# // change the column names by rearranging the 'm|f'
# // at the end of the column name
names(toydat)[-1] <- sub("^(.)(.*)", "\\2\\1", names(toydat)[-1]) 
toydat %>% 
   select(-id) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
       names_to = c(".value", "gender"), 
              names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[mf]$)") %>%
       mutate(gender = case_when(gender == 'm' ~ 'mother', TRUE ~ 'father'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#   gender income   edu ethnicity
#   <chr>   <int> <int>     <int>
# 1 mother      1     2         1
# 2 father      5     5         1
# 3 mother      5     4         3
# 4 father      4     4         2
# 5 mother      3     3         4
# 6 father      2     2         4
# 7 mother      4     5         2
# 8 father      3     1         3
# 9 mother      2     1         5
#10 father      1     3         5
#11 mother      1     2         1
#12 father      5     5         1
#13 mother      5     4         3
#14 father      4     4         2
#15 mother      3     3         4
#16 father      2     2         4
#17 mother      4     5         2
#18 father      3     1         3
#19 mother      2     1         5
#20 father      1     3         5
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun!

Comment: Hi @akrun, just a followup question: what if `mf` is at the end of the names? How to `names_sep` in a regex way?

Comment: @cliu In that case you do `names_sep = "(<=[a-z])(?=[mf]$)")` and also needs changes in `names_to = c( ".value", "gender)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the code. I tried but the variables are not split. Please see my edit to the question

Comment: @cliu in the edit, is the data used the same or have column names changed?

Comment: @cliu There is a typo.  I forgot to add `?` in `<=`

Comment: @cliu If you check my update, it is working with that typo fixed